# Start custom .NET C# (MAUI) app over Google assistant (speech over action) - does not work

Tags: c#, .net, maui, google-assistant

i say "ok Google open MyApp" - but only the website search opens.
Where shall i write **the name of my app** so that Google Assistant recognizes it and can open it?

I have this custom app: [Communitytoolkit MVVM MAUI Sample](https://github.com/tsjdev-apps/communitytoolkit-mvvm-maui-sample)
I start it on an S22 Ultra mobile device over USB connection - **this works** when start over Visual Studio (from Dev PC) or over click on my android device. Also Debugging and "Hot reload" works.

I used also an action from Google Assistant which writes my app name exactly - but no luck.
Does anyone have some advice what i have to do, that Google Assistant recognizes my app?

**I tried **: saying on my S22 Ultra: "ok Google open MyApp"  ('MyApp' is my app name)
**Expected**: My app is opened.
**Happened**: WebSite with the a search to 'MyApp' is opened.

Edit: I want this **without** any sort of *payment* like with "Google Assistant plugin" for initial fee for developer.

Comment: Is your app already in the Play store?

Comment: My app is not in the store. 
I use the direct deployment over start from local device over Visual Studio.

Thank you Jason for reply.

Comment: a quick look at the docs indicates that it needs to be deployed to the store for this to work.  There is a Googe assistant app that you may be able to use to test locally

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your app using the Google Play Console before you can access it with Google Assistant. Android documentation says:

> When you upload your app using the Google Play console, Google
> registers the capabilities declared in your app and makes them
> available for users to access from Assistant.

Android provides a [Google Assistant plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/test-tool) that can be triggered on test devices directly from the test tool window during development and testing.

For more details, refer to the official documentation: [Google Assistant for Android | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/overview)

Comment: Hello Dongzhi Wang (MSFT),

sorry I want this without any sort of payment like with "Google Assistant plugin" for initial fee for developer. 
If it is not possible, then ok, the answer is "not possible" with Google Assistant without initial payment.

Comment: Yes, you have to upload to the store to use it.

Comment: @FrankDzaebel You can mark this answer or your answer as answer to help more people.

Answer (score 0):

According to the people answering here it is **not possible** without payment.

Thanks for Jason and Dongzhi